# Выбор всего текста до определенного слова (регулярные выражения)

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

задача в следующем:
Есть строки: "test/test/chars" "test/test"
Как написать регулярное выражение, чтобы выделялось только "test/test" в обоих слуаях
Я пробовал написать .*(?=/chars), но оно работает только в первом случае ("test/test/chars"), без chars оно не выделяет ничего.
Язык программирования python
Пробовал:

```
re.findall('.*(?=\/chars)', 'test/test')
re.findall('.*(?=\/chars)', 'test/test/chars')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, сделайте свой вопрос понятнее. Укажите язык программирования, добавьте ваш код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в вашем случае впереди надо искать либо `/chars` либо конец строки `$`

```
.*?(?=\/chars|$)
```

либо,

```
(.*?)(?>\/chars)?$
```

последнее дастат результат `test/test` для строки `test/test/chars`, но для строки `test/tests/chars1` вернет всю строку целиком

Comment: не понятно... зачем тут регулярки, когда нужно искать именно "test/test""

Comment: вообще это используется для DRF, в методе lookup_value_regex

Comment: Только ни один из способов, указанных в ответе, не работает. Я попробовал на сайте regex101.com

Comment: то есть, вместо 'test' может быть любое другое слово?

Comment: да, абсолютно любое слово(причем, может быть несколько слов через слэш). Главное чтобы на конце chars не выделялось, если оно есть

Comment: Извиняюсь, способ рабочий, просто я не так понял

Answer (score 0):

Если "да, абсолютно любое слово(причем, может быть несколько слов через слэш). Главное чтобы на конце chars не выделялось, если оно есть –
Антон Бондарь", тогда может проще chars вытолкнуть?

```
import re

s = 'test/test/chars'
result = re.sub(r'chars$', '', s)
print(result)
```

И это все тоже не очень...
Если это (я предполагаю) часть http, может стоит просто разобрать по / , проверить последнее и если 'chars' - удалить последнее?
Или если известно количество нужных "узлов", обрезать список по длине.

Comment: Тогда уж "выталкивать" `r'/chars$'`.

Comment: Как бы я и пытаюсь выяснить, что именно нужно... ) мистер @GrAnd

Answer (score 0):

если вам известна подстрока до которой вы хотите выделить текст, то можно попробовать задать ее как переменную и тогда можно использовать, например, такую регулярку:

```
text = 'test/test/chars/chars2'
stop = 'char'

search(fr'(.+?){stop}', text).group(1)
```

результат:

```
'test/test/'
```